# Using a class function inside another function in the same class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

How would I go about using the function swap inside the class function rotate matrix? I haven't been able to find any answers to this.

```
void matrix::swap(int& a, int& b)
{
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
}

void matrix::rotateMatrix()
{

    int n = m_matrixSize;
    int level = 0;
    int last = n-1;
    int numOfLevels = n/2 ;

    while(level < numOfLevels)
    {
        for(int i = level;i < last; i++)
        {
            swap(matrix[level][i], matrix[i] [last]);
            swap(matrix[level][i], matrix[last][last - i + level]);
            swap(matrix[level][i], matrix[ last - i + level][level]);
        }//end for
        ++level;
        --last;
     }//end while
}//end rotateMatrix
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: What if... You have `using namespace std;` sitting up at the top of your file and instead of getting `matrix::swap` you're getting `std::swap`? This is just a guess, mind you, and I'm voting to close due to lack of [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Like someone mentioned above I just had to use the scope operator in front of swap. So matrix::swap, fixed the problem. I also had the name of the array incorrectly labeled.